# Where to keep product information?

Tags: account, product, asset

I use Salesforce to keep track of the customers my company has. We are a software vendor and we need to keep track of the software version our customers install.

I can see how I can add an Asset object to an account. This lets me say how much a customer has bought and which product. But it doesn't let me specify the version the customer installed.

How would you handle that? Via a custom field?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes custom picklist field is the option.